What is the purpose of this table on RF remote controls?
On most of the RF remote controls we can see this table. Can you explain what it means?



That "table" is to mark the manufacturing date.
"23" "24" "25" are for the years "2023" "2024" and "2025."
The other numbers are for the month. 1 = Janauary, 2 = February, etc.
Your first picture has the date marked:

There's dot by the "24" and a dot by the "1" meaning that particular board was manufactured in January, 2024.
Your other picture doesn't have dots marking the date - the manufacturer skipped that step when assembling the board.

Thanks, but what a wired way to show the manufacturing date.

What is weird about it? It's utilizing a step already "necessary" in the production process of that assembly, and in a way that makes sure it's done the same way on the same spot every time with very little effort.

I meant why they did not write it simply in numbers. For example, 2024.01. :)

@Saeed Because the silk screen does not contain any editable text, you would have to edit the original design files used to generate/vectorize/rasterize the silk screen. It makes sense to print a calendar and put a sticker on top of current year/week, or a paint dot, or add a pixel/dot to the existing vectorized/rasterized silk screen.

@Justme Thank you, I appreciate it.
